# Three.js: texture to datatexture

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, three.js

I'm trying to implement a delayed webcam viewer in javascript, using Three.js for WebGL capabilities.

I need to store frames grabbed from webcam, so they can be shown after some time (some milliseconds to some seconds). I'm able to do this without Three.js, using `canvas` and `getImageData()`. You can find [an example on jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/alessandro_pezzato/fZCJ3/embedded/result/).

I'm trying to find a way to do this without canvas, but using Three.js `Texture` or `DataTexture` object. [Here an example of what I'm trying](http://jsfiddle.net/alessandro_pezzato/mJEVg/). The problem is that I cannot find how to copy the image from a `Texture` (`image` is of type `HTMLVideoElement`) to another.

In `rotateFrames()` function the older frame should be lost and newer should replace, like in a FIFO. But the line

```js
frames[i].image = frames[i + 1].image;
```

is just copying the reference, not the texture data. I guess `DataTexture` should do this, but I'm not able to get a `DataTexture` out of a `Texture` or `HTMLVideoElement`.

Any idea?

**Warning:** you must have a camera and allow the browser to use it to get examples working. And obviously, you must have an updated browser.

Comment: Not sure I get it, but there should be a way to do it without copying bytes manually, just rotating pointers. I had a similar project and used multiple off screen canvas and built-in drawImage() to transfer to the screen. That's very fast, because Chrome does all the work on the GPU directly. So, if you want to use shaders/three.js I'd prepare the final canvas and just update the texture. Does that makes sense?

Comment: Yes, I've done this in a similar project in C++. Rotating pointers is is THE way, [see this image](http://imageshack.us/a/img259/8400/delayedvideo.gif). But every new frame need to be **copied** to the images history array (every time in a different position). If you do not copy data, but only pointers, you lose old frames, because every pointer will point to the newer frane,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what your looking for??

http://fiddle.jshell.net/m4Bh7/10/

Edit:

```
function onFrame(dt) {
    if (video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA) { /* new frame available from webcam */
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0,videoWidth,videoHeight);
        frames[framesNum - 1].image.data = new Uint8Array(context.getImageData(0,0,videoWidth, videoHeight).data.buffer);
        frames[framesNum - 1].needsUpdate = true;
    }
}
```

This is the most important part: It makes a copy of the frame and saves it as a data in a dataTexture.

```
function rotateFrames() {
    for (var i = 0; i != framesNum - 1; ++i) {
/*
         * FIXME: this does not work!
         */
        frames[i].image.data = frames[i + 1].image.data;
        frames[i].needsUpdate = true;
    }
}
```

This copies then the data from texture to texture in the frames.

new version:http://fiddle.jshell.net/hWL2E/4/

```
function onFrame(dt) {
    if (video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA) { /* new frame available from webcam */
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0,videoWidth,videoHeight);
         var frame = new THREE.DataTexture(new Uint8Array(context.getImageData(0,0,videoWidth, videoHeight).data.buffer) ,videoWidth,videoHeight);
        frames[framesNum - 1] = frame;
        frames[framesNum - 1].needsUpdate = true;
        sprites[framesNum - 1].map = frames[framesNum - 1];
    }
}
```

It generates a new texture every frame for the video images.

```
function rotateFrames() {
    for (var i = 0; i != framesNum - 1; ++i) {
/*
         * FIXME: this does not work!
         */
        frames[i] = frames[i + 1];
        sprites[i].map = frames[i];

    }
}
```

this is what makes it better. Becuase it reuses the textures that were used, means that it doesn't need to be resent to the GPU.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Please explain in the answer what you are doing and I'll accept the answer.  When you call `frames[i].image.data = frames[i + 1].image.data;` are you copying the framebuffer or just moving references?

Comment: I added a small explanation and a better version.